# How to pass exit code to a function in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

let's say I have this logging function in bash .

```
function report {
    echo "Log message: [$@]  time:  " `date` >> reports.txt
}
```

And I call it each time I need like this.

```
report running python 
python3 script.py 
report python script ended
```

Now, I would also like to the log message the exist code from `script.py`

I could obviously do this using `report python script ended with $? exit code` 
but is there a way not to explicitly pass the argument like that, and instead fetch it from withing the function report?

I tried

```
...
echo "Log message: [$@]  time:  " `date`  with exit code $? >> reports.txt
...
```

but I always get `0` even if the script failed.

Comment: @tripleee the exit status is not being shown inside my function. It always returns 0. I can even put `$?`  between a failing command and the function, I can see the exit code turning to `1` but inside the function it is always 0.

Comment: Not where I can test now, but I'll repeat that implicit behavior will get back at you when you least expect it; I would go with explicitly capturing `$?` when you need it.

Comment: Ok, by explicit you mean, I should do as `report foo bar $?` and capture it inside the function that way right?

Answer (score 3):

`$?` isn't reset until you run another command, so you should be able to capture it as the first action of `report`:

```
report () {
    status=$?
    ...
    printf 'Log message: [%s] time: %s with exit code %d\n' "$1" "$(date)" "$status"
}
```

Note that you should pass the log message as a single argument, rather than as an arbitrary sequence of words.

```
report "running python"
python3 script.py
report "python script ended"
```

It might be cleaner, though, to have the exit status be passed directly as an argument, for example, `python3 script.py; status=$?; ...; report "python script ended" "$status"`. This frees you from having to make sure that `report` is called immediately after the command whose status you want to log. (This also allows you to ignore status if it doesn't apply, as with the call prior to `script.py`.)

Comment: Thanks, one thing I don't understand. Why are you calling `"$1" "$(date)" "$status"` in other words `$?` and `$status` in the same line? Don't they mean/do the exact same thing?

Comment: You capture `$?` into `status` so that you still have the value when `$?` gets overwritten by the next external command you execute (`printf` here).  For what it's worth, this is what I tried to suggest in a comment, which you said didn't work.

Comment: Well, I still can't get the status inside the function. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Maybe, different bash versions

Comment: If there are any statements between `status=$?` and the `printf` that uses `$status`, the value of `$?` would be changed in between, so `$status` and `$?` do *not* necessarily have the same value at that point. The version of `bash` should not make any difference.